# Mean of a row with binary outcome?

Tags: r, binary, row, mean

I have a dataset containing a variable that was measured on a Likert scale. To produce some descriptives I want to calculate the mean of a row for 2 possible outcomes. The outcomes are 0(not donated) 1 (donated). The variable is called donated. The variable that I want to calculate the mean from per outcome is called AWB01W14.

My code is:

```
# Specify data frame
survey %>%                                      

# Specify group indicator, column, function
group_by(survey$donated) %>%                        
summarise_at(vars(AWB01W14, na.rm = TRUE, dims = 1),
        list(name = mean))
```

I receive the following error:

```
Error: Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector. x Subscript has the wrong type `logical`. ℹ It must be numeric or character. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I have tried to convert the variables to numeric. It gave me this code.

```
survey$donated = as.numeric(survey$donated)
survey$AWB01W14 = as.numeric(survey$AWB01W14)



# Specify data frame
survey %>%                                      

# Specify group indicator, column, function
group_by(survey$donated) %>%                        
summarise_at(vars(AWB01W14, na.rm = TRUE, dims = 1),
        list(name = mean))
```

Yet is still receive the same error.

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Glancing at this, it looks like the issue is with `group_by(survey$donated)`. Try just `group_by(donated)`, as group_by uses tidyselect (unquoted column names)

Comment: Without some sample data / a minimal reproducible example, its hard to say for sure though!